# jquery selector wont work when multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a little problem with my jquery selector. The jquery code works fine when I have only one list item. But when I have more than one, `chatid` have the value of the first list item. Why get I always the id of the first list item?

**my html and foreach loop:**

```
   <ul data-role="listview" id="uItem1" data-inset="true">
    <?php foreach ($result as $keyres => $rowres): ?>

        <li><a class="chat" id="<?php echo $rowres['id']; ?>" href="accept.php">chat</a></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

**my jquery:**

```
$("#uItem1 > li > a").click(function() {
    var chatid = $("#uItem1 > li > a").attr('id');

    $.ajax({ url: 'read.php',
     data: {chatid},
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(output) {
                //  alert(output);
              }
    });                     

   });
```

Comment: Iterate over `$("#uItem1 > li > a")` using `each`, create an array and pass array to server through ajax.

Comment: That's because `attr()` only gets the attribute for the first element in the collection, it can't get the attribute for all the elements. What you probably wanted was just `var chatid = this.id`

Comment: You don't have to user the same selector again in the process function. use simply `var chatid = this.id;`  to get id of the item being processed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to use `$(this)`

```
var chatid = $(this).attr('id');
```

and while you use foreach in php to generate elements maybe you will need

```
$("#uItem1").on('click',' > li > a',function() {
```

And as @Rory mentioned in comments you can use `this.id`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sure .. but I just like jquery way while he already using jquery

Comment: Fair enough, but it's better practice and faster to access the properties of an element already accessible than it is to create a new jQuery object just to retrieve a single property.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for sure I agree with you but I just don't know about the OP performance to not confused about js and jquery .. so I just keep him in his own track .. anyway I update my answer with that  :)

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
var chatid = $("#uItem1 > li > a").attr('id');
```

To:

```
var chatid = this.id;
var chatid = $(this).attr('id');   // For some reason if the previous didn't work.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event. From there you can get its `id` property. Also note that the object you're sending in the `$.ajax` call is invalid, it needs a key and a value. Try this:

```
$("#uItem1 > li > a").click(function() {
    var chatid = this.id;

    $.ajax({ url: 'read.php',
        data: {
            'chatid': chatid 
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(output) {
            //  alert(output);
        }
    });                     
});
```